# DBF query with Joins and Group By - C#

Tags: c#, join, group-by, foxpro, dbf

My accounting program has data stored in DBFs (I know, very old). I am trying to get a list of uncollected invoices of an agent through C# (VFPOLEDB) : client_id, date of invoice, unpayed_amount (all or partial), invoice_nr - for future insertion in android tablet sqlite. Information is stored like this (summary):

```
partners.dbf - partner catalog - client_id, agent
invoices.dbf - invoice table   - invoice nr, date, client_id, amount
payments.dbf - payments        - invoice nr, amount_payed
```

I tried using query :

```
SELECT 
          a.invoice_nr, 
          a.client_id, 
          a.date, 
          ROUND(a.amount - SUM(b.amount_payed), 2) as due 
       from 
          invoices a 
             LEFT JOIN payments b 
                on a.invoice_nr = b.invoice_nr 
       WHERE 
          a.client_id IN ( SELECT client_id 
                              FROM partners 
                              WHERE agent= 'Some agent') 
       GROUP BY 
          a.invoice_nr, 
          a.client_id, 
          a.date, 
          a.amount 
       having 
          due != 0
```

Which, interesting, in SQLite works fine. If I try to Group By only a.invoice_nr, it throws some error that Group By Clause is invalid (I read that Group By must contain all variables in select clause)

Can somebody help me adjust this query to suit my needs ? Thank you.

Comment: The error is correct and self explanatory. I am not sure why you want to change this? Why not leave the group by as is even if the other values are the same for each invoice?

Comment: Side note / Performance tip: You could benefit from a join instead of a WHERE/IN clause.

Comment: Since query runs almost instantly, I haven't seen a difference but I changed to JOIN, but still the query doesn't return what I need. I need it to return every invoice that was not collected completely. In SQLite, this query does the job, in VFPOLEDB it doesn't. Unfortunately, there isn't too much documentation on this subject since it is kind of old.

Comment: There's tons of documentation on it. Also just because a query works in SQLite doesn't mean it will work on SQL Server or Postgres or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The engine behavior in Foxpro may require you to include all non-aggregate fields in the group by.  You can change that setting to engine behavior 80 or 70.  But to simplify, since you know that a given invoice is always going to be the same client and date, you can change to..

```
select
      a.invoice_nr, 
      max( a.client_id ) client_id,
      max( a.date ) date, ... rest of query
```

Since the client and date are the same for an invoice, applying a MAX() to each will always give you the same value for said invoice.

Comment: This is a good workaround, but the query fails to return what I need. I need all invoices that are not collected completely, query which in SQLite works, but in VFPOLEDB doesn't.

Comment: @Alex, well what is missing... you have a WHERE clause that is restricting invoices based on specific clients from the partners table...

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
SELECT * from (
        SELECT a.client_id, b.date, b.invoice_nr, ROUND(b.Amount, NVL(c.total,0), 2) as Collected from partners a 
        INNER JOIN invoices b ON a.client_id = b.client_id 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT invoice_nr, SUM(amount) as total from Payments 
        GROUP BY invoice_nr) c ON b.invoice_nr = c.invoice_nr) X 
        where X.Collected != 0
```